# Sorting foreach results based on part of a string - PHP

Tags: php, foreach

I am looping through an array using foreach, and splitting the string into 2 parts.
The first part is a score and the second is an ID.
like in this case `"34 1"`, 34 is the score and 1 is the ID, separated by white space. Then I am putting the ID into a list and using it in a MySQL query after that.
The problem is that it sorts the result according to the way it is received in the initial array.

What I am trying to achieve is to sort it by the score for each id

in the example below `"34 1","7 2","29 3"` it will  sort it as `1,2,3`. But I need it to be `2,3,1`

```
<?php
$idquestionCollect = ["34 1", "7 2", "29 3"];
foreach ($idquestionCollect as $separateID) {
    [$one, $two] = explode(" ", $separateID);
    if ($one < 40) {
        $listID.= $two . "-";
    }
}
$listIDs = '"' . implode('","', explode('-', $listID)) . '"';
$listIDs = rtrim($listIDs, ',');
$query = "SELECT * FROM articles where id in($listIDs)";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['Respond'];
}
```

I was thinking that maybe there is a way to actually rearrange the `$idquestionCollect` before sending it to the foreach or maybe there is a way to do it inside the foreach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to create an array of `scores` indexed by `id` and then sort it, then extract the keys:

```
foreach ($idquestionCollect as $separateID) { 
    $parts = explode(" ", $separateID);
    if ($parts[0] < 40) {
         $listIDs[$parts[1]] = $parts[0];
    }
}        
asort($listIDs);
$listIDs = implode(',', array_keys($listIDs));
```

Another way for fun:

```
preg_match_all('/(\d+) (\d+)/', implode('-', $idquestionCollect), $matches);
$listIDs = array_combine($matches[2], $matches[1]);
asort($listIDs);
$listIDs = implode(',', array_keys($listIDs));
```

For your data both yield:

```
2,3,1
```

Comment: This just reverse order the results. but not sorting the IDs according to the scores

Comment: I see now...  Edited.

Comment: The regex solution sounds a bit more complicated, but it works indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a solution like this:

```
$idquestionCollect = ["34 1", "7 2", "29 3", "29 4", "28 5", "27 6", "27 7", "28 8", "28 9", "34 10", "34 11", "34 12", "34 13"];
$results = [];
foreach ($idquestionCollect as $separateID) {
    [$one, $two] = explode(" ", $separateID);
    $results[] = [
        "id" => rtrim($two),
        "result" => rtrim($one),
    ];
}
usort($results, function($el1, $el2){
    return $el1['result'] > $el2['result'];
});
$listIDs = '"' . implode('","', array_column($results, 'id'));
$query = "SELECT * FROM articles where id in($listIDs)";
...
```